# Load array of images into slider in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used a [slider from this](https://github.com/avijitnagare/AutoImageSlider) in my project.

In this slider they are using static images to pass to the slider and these images are visible in slider. But i have array of images coming from service, i passed this array to the slider, the slider works fine but it does not show images in the slider. I'm confused that why it is not displaying it. My code for slider is,

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"property_images"];
NSLog(@"GGG %@",arrayOfImages);


//self.imagesData=[[NSArray alloc]init];
self.imagesData = arrayOfImages;  //[_Image1 mutableCopy];  //@[@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg"];
NSLog(@"Image Array is %@",_imagesData);
for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
index=0;


// Progammatically init a TAPageControl with a custom dot view.
self.customPageControl2 = [[TAPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,self.scrollView.frame.origin.y+self.scrollView.frame.size.height,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,40)];//CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.scrollView.frame) - 100, CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame), 40)
// Example for touch bullet event
self.customPageControl2.delegate      = self;
self.customPageControl2.numberOfPages = self.imagesData.count;
self.customPageControl2.dotSize       = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * self.imagesData.count, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame));
[self.view addSubview:self.customPageControl2];
```

and further functions of slider are this,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(runImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;
    }
}



 -(void)runImages{
        self.customPageControl2.currentPage=index;
        if (index==self.imagesData.count-1) {
            index=0;
        }else{
            index++;
        }
        [self TAPageControl:self.customPageControl2 didSelectPageAtIndex:index];
    }

        - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];


    }

        - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        NSInteger pageIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame);
        self.customPageControl2.currentPage = pageIndex;
        index=pageIndex;
    }
    // Example of use of delegate for second scroll view to respond to bullet touch event
    - (void)TAPageControl:(TAPageControl *)pageControl didSelectPageAtIndex:

        (NSInteger)currentIndex
    {
        index=currentIndex;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * currentIndex, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)) animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: If you drop the timer code, do you see the images in the slider? I mean, just add one image in, see if it's there and then move on from there.

Comment: Static images are showing on the screen but array of images which i'm passing are not visible. @JohnnyRockex

Comment: @HamzaImran Why you are not using UICollectionView?

Comment: Actually, i'm new and not aware of it and time is short that to switch from one method to another. @Tuhin

Comment: @HamzaImran Then its your call mate. Otherwise in my opinion UICollectionView is the best in your case for more powerful handling and will give you pretty much everything which you wants to do. You just need to set it up properly with a layout.

Comment: can u explain it , how can i do that if i have time i can apply this approach. @Tuhin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SDWebImage Library for download image from server.

Objective-C:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
 //   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]]; comment this line and replace with bottom line

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**Whole code**

```
  for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
       [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];    
       [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
```

[SDWebImage Source](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: @Hamza Imran what does contains this arrayOfImages ?

Comment: It contains the array of images coming from service. I want to show it in horizantal way . @KKRocks

Comment: How can i display them in a horizontal scroll way? The array not contain fixed images it varies when user select them. @KKRocks

Comment: if your slider already works with static images then you only need to replace your code with my answer.

Comment: i haven't used imageview in storyboard its only scrollview outlet in my .h file. Can u explain what to write in imageView in ur code? @KKRocks

Comment: it doesnt matter if your image displayed with local image in slider as mentioned in question then you have only download image through sdwebimage .

Comment: Bro, i'm not getting it can u edit ur answer in my code? . @KKRocks

Comment: Can u edit it according to my code? I'm getting error while using ur code. @KKRocks

Answer (score 0):

This is your basic setup for the scrollView:

```
//data
NSArray * imageArray = @[@"a.jpg",@"b.jpg",@"c.jpg"];

//view
UIScrollView * scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

//add in
float x = 0;
float imageWidth = 320;
for (int n = 0; n < imageArray.count; n++){

    UIImageView * iv = [UIImageView new];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, imageWidth, 200);
    iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageArray[n]];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    iv.clipsToBounds = true;
    [scrollView addSubview:iv];

    x+=imageWidth;
}

//update content size
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, 200);
```